# Firebase data snapshot returns key but no .val()

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following data where querying for the value of user/(userID)/(topic) returns null:

```
{
  "topic" : {
    "cafe" : {
      "-KWoHbBXzWlD8aHBjg6Z" : {
        "count" : 0,
        "id" : "00qMXXXeYkbCbmjajoe4XZeIPuo1",
        "text" : "A new message",
        "time" : "2016-11-17T21:56:26.036Z"
      },
      "-KWpBzT83S_RB3wVwZ2u" : {
        "count" : 3,
        "id" : "zTSpSTqyRcaJf0MlYl15gBnvYdj2",
        "text" : "Hello",
        "time" : "2016-11-18T02:11:29.818Z"
      }
    },
    "pomodoro" : {
      "-KWoJhC9V1mLznt7jGwF" : {
        "count" : 3,
        "id" : "00qMXXXeYkbCbmjajoe4XZeIPuo1",
        "text" : "Tomato! #tomato",
        "time" : "2016-11-17T22:05:34.933Z"
      }
    }
  },
  "user" : {
    "00qMXXXeYkbCbmjajoe4XZeIPuo1" : {
      "pomodoro" : "2016-11-18T14:20:32.800Z"
    },
    "zTSpSTqyRcaJf0MlYl15gBnvYdj2" : {
      "cafe" : "2016-11-18T14:24:32.968Z"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
// inside the constructor
this.database = firebase.database().ref()

//relevant function
databaseListenerOn = () => {

  // does not work correctly
  let userPath = `user/${this.props.userID}/${this.state.topic}`
  this.database.child(userPath).on('value', data => {
    this.setState({time: data.val()})
    console.log(data.key)
    console.log(data.val())
  })

  //works correctly 
  let messagePath = `topic/${this.state.topic}`
  this.database.child(messagePath).on('value', data => {
    let messages = []
    data.forEach(message => {
      messages.push({
        count: message.val().count,
        id: message.val().id,
        key: message.key,
        text: message.val().text,
        time: message.val().time
      })
    })
    this.setState({messages: this.state.messages.cloneWithRows(messages)})
  })
}
```

logging `data.key` correctly returns 'cafe' or 'pomodoro'. However, `data.val()` returns null and I am unable to access the string timestamp.

Using similar code, I am able to successfully access other data where `data.val()` returns objects so I'm confused as to what I could be doing wrong. I have looked at similar issues on this site and the Google Group, but have not found an answer for my particular situation.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. Can you set up a minimal JSBin that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I have never used JSBin before, but I will see if I can replicate the issue. For now I have added the JSON as text as well as some additional information.

Comment: A jsfiddle or something similar is fine too. I mostly just want to see the problem happen, because I'm likely overlooking something in the code.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/nicecilowu/1/edit?js,console,output (I hope I shared this correctly) When I tried an isolated query, the data was returned correctly so it must be something else in my react-native app that's causing the issue. However, I am unsure as to why the other .on method inside databaseListenerOn works correctly : /

Comment: The jsbin doesn't run, since you haven't included the configuration data. If I can't see how to reproduce the problem, it'll be hard to help.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/dokepet/1/edit?js,console

Comment: I believe the issue is that I don't have the user ID in  `user/${this.props.userID}/${this.state.topic}` when I run the query - that would also explain why the other query works correctly.

Comment: Thank you for helping me isolate the issue! I'm still new to all of this and wouldn't have been able to figure it out without your help.

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem. For future questions: isolate the problem in something like a jsbin, so that you can give the [minimal code needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I didn't wait for Firebase to return the userID before running my query:

```
// this.props.userID is undefined    
let userPath = `user/${this.props.userID}/${this.state.topic}`
```

The solution was to call `this.databaseListenerOn()` within `onAuthStateChanged` to ensure that it's called once I have the userID.